# Difference between values based on condition

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two dataframes and I want to find the difference between dataframe1 and dataframe2 based on the condition. What I mean is the following:

df.ref_well:

```
zone depth
a    34
b    23
c    11
d    35
e    -9999
```

df_well

```
zone depth
a    17
c    15
d    25
f    11
```

what I want is to generate the df3 with the zone name and the difference between depth of the same zones in df1 and df3:

df3 = well- ref well (the same zones)

```
zone depth
a    17
b    -9999
c    -4
d    10
e    -9999
```

I have tried to iterate through dfs separately and identify the same zones, and if they are equal to find the difference:

```
ref_well_zone_count=len(df_ref_well.iloc[:,0])
well_zone_count=len(df_well.iloc[:,0])


delta_depth=[]

for ref_zone in range(ref_well_zone_count):
    for well_zone in range(well_zone_count):
        if df_ref_well.iloc[ref_zone,0]==df_well.iloc[well_zone,0]:
            delta_tvdss.append(df_well.iloc[well_zone, 1] - df_ref_well.iloc[ref_zone, 1])
```

The problem is I can't fill the results into the new column I am not able to insert them, so when I try adding the delta_depth as a column it says that:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

But if I print out the results it calculates perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify what you want to do if there is no match. So I will assume no match means depth = 0

Link 2 df together using merge, then fill those that doesn't have a match will have 0 by default:

```
df3 = pd.merge(ref_well,df_well, on=['zone'], how='outer').fillna(0)
```

Calculate the difference and put it back

```
df3['diff'] = df3.depth_x - df3.depth_y
```